# Changing forecolor for buttons linked to a single function C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

So I'm trying to create a little Tic Tac Toe game with WinForms. I'm really new to C#. I've set the grid up using buttons and have linked all buttons to a single function (referred to as "ButtonClick" below) which calls this SetMove function. I'd like for X to be displayed in Blue and O in red.

```
private void SetMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
     var button = (Button)sender;
     if (turn == "X")
     {
          button.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
          button.Text = turn;
          turn = "O";
     }
     else
     {
          button.ForeColor = Color.Red;
          button.Text = turn;
          turn = "X";
     }
     button.Enabled = false;
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsFree(sender, e))
    {
        SetMove(sender, e);
        IsGameOver();
    }
}
```

I use the sender to find out which button had called the function and then try to update the forecolor and place the text. "ButtonClick" function checks if the position is first free by checking if `button.Enabled == true` and then after placing the X or O it checks for the win condition.

So far it's behaviour is that it places the text but the colour is set to black. Although on the design tab I've got them all set to blue as X goes first. If I was to display some text at the start when loading the form (before any player makes a turn), it shows up as blue but any text inputs which are made by the program are shown as black.

***EDIT 1: Full code:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TicTacToeFE
{
    public partial class TicTacToe : Form
    {
        public static string turn = "X";
        public TicTacToe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private static bool IsFree(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            if(button.Enabled)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void SetMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var button = (Button)sender;
            if (turn == "X")
            {
                button.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                button.Text = turn;
                turn = "O";
            }
            else
            {
                button.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                button.Text = turn;
                turn = "X";
            }
            button.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void IsGameOver()
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> 
            { TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, CenterLeft, CenterCenter,
            CenterRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight };
            DialogResult result = new DialogResult();
            if (buttons.All(x => x.Text != ""))
            {
                if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[1].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[2].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[3].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[3].Text == buttons[5].Text && buttons[3].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[3].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[6].Text == buttons[7].Text && buttons[6].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[6].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[6].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[3].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[6].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[1].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[1].Text == buttons[7].Text && buttons[1].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[1].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[2].Text == buttons[5].Text && buttons[2].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[2].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[2].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else if (buttons[2].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[2].Text == buttons[6].Text && buttons[2].Text != "")
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[2].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = MessageBox.Show("It was a tie game. Would you like to reset ? ", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                }

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[1].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[2].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[3].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[3].Text == buttons[5].Text && buttons[3].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[3].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[6].Text == buttons[7].Text && buttons[6].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[6].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[6].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[3].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[6].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[1].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[1].Text == buttons[7].Text && buttons[1].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[1].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[2].Text == buttons[5].Text && buttons[2].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[2].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[2].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[0].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[0].Text == buttons[8].Text && buttons[0].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[0].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (buttons[2].Text == buttons[4].Text && buttons[2].Text == buttons[6].Text && buttons[2].Text != "")
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show($"The winner is {buttons[2].Text}! Would you like to reset?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Reset()
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>
            { TopRight, TopCenter, TopLeft, CenterLeft, CenterCenter,
            CenterRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight };

            foreach(Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Text = "";
                button.Enabled = true;
                turn = "X";
            }
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            if(IsFree(sender, e))
            {
                SetMove(sender, e);
                IsGameOver();
            }

        }

        private void ButtonHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(IsFree(sender, e))
            {
                Button button = (Button)sender;
                button.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                if (turn == "X")
                {
                    button.Text = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    button.Text = "O";
                }
            }
        }

        private void ButtonLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsFree(sender, e))
            {
                Button button = (Button)sender;
                button.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace TicTacToeFE
{
    partial class TicTacToe
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(TicTacToe));
            this.TopLeft = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.TopCenter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.TopRight = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CenterLeft = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CenterCenter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CenterRight = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.BottomLeft = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.BottomCenter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.BottomRight = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // TopLeft
            // 
            this.TopLeft.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.TopLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.TopLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.TopLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopLeft.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.TopLeft.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.TopLeft.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.TopLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.TopLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.TopLeft.Name = "TopLeft";
            this.TopLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.TopLeft.TabIndex = 0;
            this.TopLeft.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.TopLeft.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.TopLeft.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.TopLeft.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // TopCenter
            // 
            this.TopCenter.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.TopCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.TopCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.TopCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopCenter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.TopCenter.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.TopCenter.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.TopCenter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 0);
            this.TopCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.TopCenter.Name = "TopCenter";
            this.TopCenter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.TopCenter.TabIndex = 1;
            this.TopCenter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.TopCenter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.TopCenter.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.TopCenter.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // TopRight
            // 
            this.TopRight.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.TopRight.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.TopRight.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.TopRight.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopRight.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.TopRight.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.TopRight.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.TopRight.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.TopRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 0);
            this.TopRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.TopRight.Name = "TopRight";
            this.TopRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.TopRight.TabIndex = 2;
            this.TopRight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.TopRight.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.TopRight.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.TopRight.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // CenterLeft
            // 
            this.CenterLeft.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.CenterLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.CenterLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.CenterLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterLeft.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.CenterLeft.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.CenterLeft.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.CenterLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 200);
            this.CenterLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.CenterLeft.Name = "CenterLeft";
            this.CenterLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.CenterLeft.TabIndex = 3;
            this.CenterLeft.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CenterLeft.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.CenterLeft.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.CenterLeft.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // CenterCenter
            // 
            this.CenterCenter.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.CenterCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.CenterCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.CenterCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterCenter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.CenterCenter.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.CenterCenter.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.CenterCenter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 200);
            this.CenterCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.CenterCenter.Name = "CenterCenter";
            this.CenterCenter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.CenterCenter.TabIndex = 4;
            this.CenterCenter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CenterCenter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.CenterCenter.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.CenterCenter.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // CenterRight
            // 
            this.CenterRight.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.CenterRight.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.CenterRight.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.CenterRight.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterRight.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.CenterRight.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.CenterRight.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.CenterRight.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.CenterRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 200);
            this.CenterRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.CenterRight.Name = "CenterRight";
            this.CenterRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.CenterRight.TabIndex = 5;
            this.CenterRight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CenterRight.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.CenterRight.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.CenterRight.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // BottomLeft
            // 
            this.BottomLeft.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.BottomLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.BottomLeft.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.BottomLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomLeft.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomLeft.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.BottomLeft.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.BottomLeft.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.BottomLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 400);
            this.BottomLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.BottomLeft.Name = "BottomLeft";
            this.BottomLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.BottomLeft.TabIndex = 6;
            this.BottomLeft.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.BottomLeft.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.BottomLeft.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.BottomLeft.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // BottomCenter
            // 
            this.BottomCenter.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.BottomCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.BottomCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.BottomCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomCenter.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomCenter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.BottomCenter.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.BottomCenter.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.BottomCenter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 400);
            this.BottomCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.BottomCenter.Name = "BottomCenter";
            this.BottomCenter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.BottomCenter.TabIndex = 7;
            this.BottomCenter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.BottomCenter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.BottomCenter.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.BottomCenter.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // BottomRight
            // 
            this.BottomRight.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.BottomRight.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.BottomRight.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            this.BottomRight.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomRight.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.BottomRight.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.BottomRight.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe Print", 60F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.BottomRight.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.BottomRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 400);
            this.BottomRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.BottomRight.Name = "BottomRight";
            this.BottomRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.BottomRight.TabIndex = 8;
            this.BottomRight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.BottomRight.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
            this.BottomRight.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonLeave);
            this.BottomRight.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHover);
            // 
            // TicTacToe
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 600);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BottomRight);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BottomCenter);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BottomLeft);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CenterRight);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CenterCenter);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CenterLeft);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TopRight);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TopCenter);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TopLeft);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "TicTacToe";
            this.Text = "Tic Tac Toe";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button CenterLeft;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button CenterCenter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button CenterRight;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BottomLeft;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BottomCenter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BottomRight;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button TopLeft;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button TopCenter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button TopRight;
    }
}
```

Set Text = X for the top left and it shows up in blue.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Vu8.png

When I run the program and place X it shows up in grey (blue X is from setting Text property to X in the program before starting up): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VDrp.png

Comment: Just a guess: a disabled control ignores the color you choosed for you text and always applies the same "control disabled text color" (black or dark gray by default). Have a try commenting the `button.Enabled = false;` line

Comment: Agree with Gian, it's greyed out because the button is disabled.  You could leave the buttons enabled, then change your `IsFree()` function to `return (((Button)sender).Text == "");`.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it. It does mess up my ButtonHover and ButtonLeave functions but I'll try to find another way around that. Probably check the colour of the text too as Hover should display it in grey,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is disabled the text by default becomes greyed out instead of the forecolor which it was set to, credit to Gian Paolo.

Comment: Don't forget to update your `IsFree()` function as in my post...

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I'd reduce your code using the [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
private void SetMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Text = turn;
    //button.Enabled = false; <-- leave the buttons enabled for the colors
    button.ForeColor = (button.Text == "X") ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;                        
    turn = (turn == "X") ? "O" : "X";
}
```

Keep the colors by leaving the Buttons enabled all the time, yhen change `IsFree()` to:

```
private static bool IsFree(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return (((Button)sender).Text == "");
}
```